# Getting exception on email or sending an email in Phonegap

Tags: android, email, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an android application using **phonegap** in which i display an error message on alert.
Now i want to send this alert message via Email to the particular email id.

Can any one give me solution on this.Here are some similar questions posted before but no one give any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EmailComposer plugin for phonegap,  [link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) , after installing plugin you can send mail from javascript by this code

```
window.plugin.email.open({
    to:      ['test@test.com'],
    cc:      ['cc@cc.cc'],
    bcc:     ['johne@john.com', 'john@john.com'],
    subject: 'Error',
    body:    'Your Error message'
});
```

Comment: thanks arjun..bt when i include plugins this no action is performed.

Comment: sorry?    no action is performed.  means

Comment: when i write this code on button click it will cannot enter in open method..i think i done something wrong with including plugin can you please provide me the steps to do this..so it will be helpful..

Comment: if you are using cmd line installation no need od any editing , cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git && cordova prepare, check whether new item present inside config.xml, i think you are using latest version of phonegap

Comment: No i am not going to install from cmd..i just include the activity Emailcomposer in my package and add plugin.xml file in my project and then add this line.... <!-- interface -->
    <js-module src="www/email_composer.js" name="EmailComposer">
        <clobbers target="plugin.email" />
    </js-module>                                                                                 

And this line..<plugin 
            name="Email"
            value="com.whitehedge.eos.EmailComposer" />